# POST Request Returning 500

Tags: python, web-scraping, post, networking, python-requests

I am trying to scrape `https://www.comedycellar.com/lineup/api/` which is a POST request with the following parameters:

```
action: "cc_get_shows"
json: {"date":"2024-01-10","venue":"newyork","type":"lineup"}
```

My attempt is as follows:

```
import requests
lineup_url = 'https://www.comedycellar.com/lineup/api/'
json = {"date":"2024-01-08","venue":"newyork","type":"lineup", "action": "cc_get_shows"}
response = requests.post(lineup_url, json=json)
```

However it's returning status code 500. Any ideas for getting this to work? For reference, you can go to https://www.comedycellar.com/new-york-line-up/ select a date and then in the Network section you can see the POST request being made.

Comment: 500 can indicate an actual error on the remote server.  Maybe it's because you submitted an incorrect or unexpected request, or maybe it's an actual bug in their API.  We can't tell.

Comment: @JohnGordon the request works when using the website myself so I'd imagine it's because I'm submitting an incorrect or unexpected request when doing it programatically.

Comment: Does the response body contain a useful error message?

Comment: Are you sure the api accepts json?  Usually when a form is submitted via a website, it uses plain form-data, not json.  Try using `data=json` instead of `json=json` in the post call.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have prepared the payload is wrong. Try the following instead to get the required data:

```
import json
import requests

lineup_url = 'https://www.comedycellar.com/lineup/api/'

headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Referer': 'https://www.comedycellar.com/new-york-line-up/',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

payload = {
    'action': 'cc_get_shows',
    'json': json.dumps({"date":"2024-01-08","venue":"newyork","type":"lineup"})
}

response = requests.post(lineup_url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```